# php percent calculation

Tags: php, percentage

how to implement calculation of percents:

```
$x=3;
$y = 100\$x;  // 3.333..
$x*$y  - and here I need to get 100 without Observational error
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `100\$x`? that's not division... it's a namespace reference, and invalid to boot. calculating a percentage is just basic math. the fact that you're using php (or any other language) doesn't change how you calculate a percentage...

Comment: 100 / 3 is not 3.33333 to begin with...

Comment: `echo 100 == ceil($x*$y);` is THAT what you're asking for?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your backslash (`\`) is not the division symbol. You must use division `/` symbol.

Here's an example using `number_format()` which will round to two decimal places (the hundredths position).

```
$x = 3;
$y = 15;

$percent = $x/$y;
$percent_friendly = number_format( $percent * 100, 2 ) . '%'; // change 2 to # of decimals
```

Comment: You should check  if $x > 0...